# Math sequence create binding loop

Tags: javascript, binding, qml

I'm trying to create pseudo-random number based on a mathematical sequence.

I've created two seed, and a function that update the seed each time it is called :

```
property var seed1: 12;
property var seed2: 23;

function pAlea(m) {
    var res = (seed1 + seed2) % m;
    seed1 = seed2;
    seed2 = res
    return res;
}
```

Then I try to create an array containing pseudo-random values :

```
property var tab: {
    var tab = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        tab.push(pAlea(100));
    }
    return tab;
}
```

Since "res" is calculated upon the two seed, and the seed2 are updated to res, the system detect a binding loop. But it shouldn't : Here, I don't want to bind on the other var I just want its value.

How can I prevent a binding to occur beetween seed2 and res ?

and beetween seed1 and seed2 ?

and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working properly. Since you don't bind properties but just simply assign values via the = operator, I guess the binding loop is occuring somewhere else. If you want to bind properties inside a function, you need to use Qt.bind() explicitly. This code works for me:

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Rectangle {
    property var seed1: 12;
    property var seed2: 23;

    function pAlea(m) {
        var res = (seed1 + seed2) % m;
        seed1 = seed2;
        seed2 = res

        console.log("res: " + res);

        return res;
    }

    Timer {
        id: timer;
        interval: 1000; running: true; repeat: true
        onTriggered: pAlea(5);
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

### Update

Okay, after your comment I can see what your problem is. And it's in fact pretty interesting. I spent some time with this and couldn't find an answer where the binding loop comes from. But there are two ways to solve the problem:

### Solution 1

Personally I would simply use an array for the tab property and initialize it when the component's creation signal is emitted, like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Rectangle {
    property var seed1: 12;
    property var seed2: 23;
    property var tab: [];

    function pAlea(m) {
        var res = (seed1 + seed2) % m;
        seed1 = seed2;
        seed2 = res

        console.log("res: " + res);

        return res;
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        for (var i = 0; i <10; i++) {
            tab.push(pAlea(100));
        }
        console.log("tab (after completion): " + tab);
    }
}
```

### Solution 2

I found out that the binding loop problem disappears when you move the the pAlea function's logic into the property initialization, like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Rectangle {
    property var seed1: 12;
    property var seed2: 23;

    property var tab: {
        var result = [];

        var m = 100;
        for (var i = 0; i <10; i++) {
            var res = (seed1 + seed2) % m;
            seed1 = seed2;
            seed2 = res
            result.push(res);
        }

        return result;
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("finished: " + tab);
    }
}
```

Initializing properties like you did, is (at least as far as I can tell) not that common. Basically you bind the expressions inside the curly braces to the property, and since Qt does some interpretation magic, it's not always obvious how the initialization affects the properties behavior or how the bindings are resolved, for example:

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Rectangle {
    property var one: {
        "one"
    }
    property var two: {
        console.log("two");
    }
    property var three: {
        function() { console.log("three");}
    }
    property var four: {
        one+=" plus three";
    }
    property var fiveAndSix: {
        five : "five";
        six : "six";
    }
}
```

Printing the properties (in the same order as above) to the debug console in the root element's onCompleted function shows some unexpected things:

```
qml: two
qml: one: one plus three
qml: two: undefined
qml: three: function() { [code] }
qml: four: one plus three
qml: fiveAndSix: six
```

Some things are more obvious, some are surprising (but I should come to an end, even though this is interesting stuff...). Personally I would try to avoid such (I would call them) inline property definitions and rather handle initialization like shown in solution 1 or use C++ for such things.

Maybe I was able to help you at least a little bit, even if the *why* remains unclear..

Comment: You are right but I think it still is because of it. I edited my question to add the part that raise the binding loop.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I ended up with something different, but not as good as you. I finally used solution 1, but created a createArray function. Still don"t understand what is happening here.